# Creating OS disk from VHD stored in another storage account

Tags: azure-sdk-.net, azure-sdk

Have an existing PowerShell script that is creating VM's using pre-created VHD's stored in a storage account (copied across regional storage accounts for speed).

In PS we can use the following:

```
New-AzureRmDisk -DiskName $osDiskName -Disk `
(New-AzureRmDiskConfig -AccountType Premium_LRS  `
        -Location $location -CreateOption Import `
        -StorageAccountId $storageAccountId `
        -SourceUri $osVHDUri) `
    -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
$osDisk = Get-AzureRMDisk -DiskName $osDiskName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName

$VirtualMachine = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $VirtualMachine -ManagedDiskId $osDisk.Id -CreateOption Attach -Windows -StorageAccountType Premium_LRS
```

Where $storageAccountId is similar to:

```
/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/my-snapshot/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/mysnapshots -f $sourceSnapshotSubscriptionId
```

In the .net Azure SDK, I don't see a way to replicate this? When I try to create, it's saying unable to find, yet my PS works ok.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an existing disk instead of a marketplace image, use this code:

```
var managedDisk = azure.Disks.Define("myosdisk")
    .WithRegion(location)
    .WithExistingResourceGroup(groupName)
    .WithWindowsFromVhd("https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/myosdisk.vhd")
    .WithSizeInGB(128)
    .WithSku(DiskSkuTypes.PremiumLRS)
    .Create();

azure.VirtualMachines.Define("myVM")
    .WithRegion(location)
    .WithExistingResourceGroup(groupName)
    .WithExistingPrimaryNetworkInterface(networkInterface)
    .WithSpecializedOSDisk(managedDisk, OperatingSystemTypes.Windows)
    .WithExistingAvailabilitySet(availabilitySet)
    .WithSize(VirtualMachineSizeTypes.StandardDS1)
    .Create();
```

Check this [link](http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/MVC/Post/Thread/cbd2c2d7-2075-4a6a-8515-daf5aeadfe39?category=wavirtualmachinesforwindows) for further reference. Hope it helps.

Comment: The challenge is the VHD Uri is referencing a storage account location that is different. PowerShell allows you to pass the storageaccountid in, but the .net SDK has no reference for this.